# Colorbox not redirecting to my chosen URL

Tags: jquery, colorbox

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('#reset_password').live('click', function(e) { 
    parent.$.fn.colorbox.close(); 
    parent.$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){ 
    window.location.href = "search_message_thankyou.php";
        }); 
    });
});  
 </script>
```

The script closes the colorbox as I need, but then doesn't redirect to the thank you page. I look up whats happening in the console and this is the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: would this work instead: parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();  
    window.location.href = "search_message_thankyou.php";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the `bind` before you close it, like this:

```
parent.$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){ 
window.location.href = "search_message_thankyou.php";
    }); 
});
parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
```

Alternatively you could do `parent.location.href = x`.

Answer (score 1):

If your colorbox is loading content in an iframe then you might want to try

`window.parent.location.href = "search_message_thankyou.php";`

Answer (score 0):

They key is to initiate the bind from the parent page, not from the iframe.

In my own solution I used the example below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".iframe").colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true});

    if ($('.btn_OpenColorbox').length) {
        //check for existence of colorbox open button
        //bind and redirect after colorbox closes
        $(document).bind('cbox_closed', function () {
            window.location.assign('My-Redirect-Page.aspx');
        });
    }
    $('.btn_CloseColorbox').click(function () {
        //close colorbox
        parent.$.colorbox.close();
    });
}
```

There's another example here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/colorbox/jSrZSoW7P3s